# Is there a way to change network credentials just once?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server

In the course of the day I access a dozen different machines, mostly via UNC shares. To access them, I have to use a credential different from my logged in credentials.  Every 3 months or so this credential expires, so Windows will pop up a Login screen for each of the servers.  This can get super annoying since it's all the same login and password.

All these credentials are stored in the Windows Credentials Manager.  Is there a way to update the credential once and have it affect all the connections that user the same login?

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: @DavidPostill I will do that!

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

The solution is the [cmdkey](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey) command line utility, that's built-in to the OS. So I created a batch file to delete and then recreate all the credentials:

```
cmdkey /delete:server1
cmdkey /delete:server2

cmdkey /add:server1 /user:domain1\angry /pass:Password24!
cmdkey /add:server2 /user:domain1\angry /pass:Password24!
```